# Too many redirects on iPhone Safari/Chrome

Tags: ios, iphone, .htaccess, google-chrome, safari

So one of my website's project has problem with HTTPS. When I open it on the desktop Chrome/Opera/Firefox it works fine, but on the iPhone Safari/Chrome it returns me error "too many redirects". This happens only on iPhones. Here is the `.htaccess` file content which should redirects http to https and www to non-www (it's in the top of the file, there are no Redirect data in whole file):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Why did I noted a HTTPS? Because when I remove the RewriteRule from file it loads without problem.

First I tried only on Safari. I removed internet history and cookies - no help. I downloaded fresh Chrome and same problem occurs. So my problem occurs only with HTTPS tirned on... Why?

Answer (score 0):

Just merge the redirect into one using the `[OR]` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This combines your rules and should stop the server from throwing a too many redirects error. The first condition checks if HTTPs is not on and the second condition checks if `www` is present or not.

If either of those conditions fail, it will rewrite the URL using 301 redirection to use HTTPs and remove `www`.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing it.

Comment: I tried, but still same result :( You can see the website: wcbidet.eu (there is your suggestion applied now, I changed the example.com)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using following method

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: My current condition is `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80` which is pretty the same thing :)

Comment: I mean the  %{SERVER_PORT} will work instead of %{HTTPS} :)